# -(void)touchesBegan (TO A SPECIFIED UIIMAGEVIEW)

Tags: objective-c, touchesbegan

Hi I want to make it so that if you touch an image that I put on the view the -(void)checkcollision happens. The -(void)checkcollision happens, but when I touch anything. How can I say it only works if i touch a specified image. e.g. a pimple:

```
IBOutlet UIImageView *pimple;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *pimple;
```

here is the touchesBegan code

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {


    UITouch *myTouch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    [self checkcollision];
}


-(void)checkcollision {

    if (label.text = @"0") {
        label.text = @"1";
    }

    pimple.hidden = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CGPoint point = [myTouch locationInView:pimple];
if ( CGRectContainsPoint(pimple.bounds, point) ) {
    ... Touch detected.
}
```

Alternatively you can consider [`gesture recognizers`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html). You can use a tap recognizer for this case.

Comment: i put this code :        - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *myTouch = [touches anyObject];

 CGPoint point = [myTouch locationInView:pimple];
 if ( CGRectContainsCGPoint(pimple.bounds, point) ) {
  [self checkcollision];
 }
 i got this warning :implicit declaration of function 'CGRectContainsCGPoint'



and got this error:

Comment: and this error:   "_CGRectContainsCGPoint", referenced from:


      -[GameScreen touchesBegan:withEvent:] in GameScreen.o


ld: symbol(s) not found


collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

1. Subclass `UIImageView` and define your own handler
2. Check sender `- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` and compare it to your `UIImageView` instance.

Comment: ??? A bit more help... Im kind of new and in this case Im stuck with your explanation. Could you write the code then point out what it means

Comment: If I have a subclass UIImageView Im going to have to import the image right. Wont that take longer?

Comment: UIImageView is not meant to be subclassed. Apple's recommendation.

Comment: Well. ok. BUt some help please