# Error: request for member 'location' in something not a structure or union

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am creating an app where when you touch a pimple it moves to a different location. This is the code that I put:

```
pimple.location = (320, 64);
```

(I have created an IBOutlet for pimple and connected it)

I get the following error:

request for member 'location' in something not a structure or union

Here is my .m code:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *myTouch = [touches anyObject];

    CGPoint point = [myTouch locationInView:pimple];
    if ( CGRectContainsPoint(pimple.bounds, point) ) {
        [self checkcollision];
    }


}





-(void)checkcollision {

    label.text += 1;    
    pimple.hidden = YES;
    pimple.location = (320, 64);   //the error
    sad.hidden = NO;

    NSURL* popURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pop" ofType:@"mp3"]];
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef) popURL, &popID);

    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(popID);
}
```

Comment: what is location? What kind of an datatype is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location property is (probably) of type `CGPoint` (a struct), you can't just assign a point value by providing two numbers. You would typically assign it with the helper function `CGPointMake`:

```
pimple.location = CGPointMake(320, 64);
```

or:

```
CGPoint location; 
location.x = 320;
location.y = 64;
pimple.location = location;
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `pimple` is a `UIImageView` object (based on [`this SO question`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6160741/voidtouchesbegan-to-a-specified-uiimageview/6160800)), you would probably want to change its position by using the `center` property.

```
pimple.center = CGPointMake(320, 64);
```

or

```
pimple.center = (CGPoint){320, 64};
```